# Get position right in front of a Box2d body not of its center/axis - screenshot attached

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

My rectangle body below is gun that rotates around its axis (red dot) and shoots green balls.

At moment,the green balls are created based on the gun's position, however it gets the gun's center position (red dot again).

The blue blue stroke represents the gun rotation (either left or right) and where I want to create the balls, right in front of the body. I can't just use position.X + body's width/2 because it rotates.

Any idea of how I could implement it ?

[image]

Comment: Use GetworldPoint: https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h#253

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900380/box2d-get-shape-points-from-rotated-body/11908450

Comment: Thanks @iforce2d...After I get GetworldPoint of my gun body,how could I project the ball to be created right in front of the gun?
Now, the ball's creation follows the gun's rotation, but far and not aligned to the gun

Comment: You don't GetWorldPoint of your gun body. You GetWorldPoint of the local position of the bullet start point, relative to the body. Eg. if the circle is radius 1, then GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,1.1) ) would give you the point just outside the radius. And for your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164146/simple-gun-in-cocos2dbox2d-game/9167871

Comment: @iforce2d Post your answer as an answer so it can get accepted properly.